# In a mongodb aggregation query, how can I check if field's value matches one in a given array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am writing a MongoDB query, using `aggregate`.

I want to find all results that are matches based on given music preferences.

For example, here is a sample of my code

```
matchingGenres = ["CLASSIC_ROCK", "HEAVY_METAL", "POP"];
dbquery = [
        {
            $project:{
             ....
            }
        },
        {
            $match: { 
                $and: [
                    {genre: ?????}, // match if genre is in the array matchingGenres
                ...
                ]
         }
]
```

How do I match only if the documents value for the `genre` field is in the array `matchingGenres`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to match against multiple values. For example:

```
{
   $match: {
      genre: { $in: ["CLASSIC_ROCK", "HEAVY_METAL", "POP"] }
   }
}
```